# Glyphicon sometimes shows and sometimes doesnt show in my page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I downloaded v3.1.1 of Bootstrap from this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download). I am using Glyphicon in my ASP.NET MVC Project.

Problem I am facing is, in my view, I can see Glyphicon icon sometimes and it wont load sometimes. I am confused why this is happening. This is my CSS :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" style="font-size: 3em;color:grey;"></span>
```

What I did is, I put bootstrap.min.css inside Content folder and put Fonts folder inside my project and outside content folder.

Why I did like this is, when I put fonts folder inside content, it was not showing at all. so I did like this.

Project Structure :

**Projectname->Content->bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.css**

**Projectname-> Fonts**

My code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

           <h3> Image <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" style="font-size: 3em;color:grey;"></span></h3>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML, CSS and folder structure, otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: @Milanzor I updated my post. please have a look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Dont change the default folder structure otherwise you may have to change url in bootstrap.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- opentype'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Let the fonts be under contents folder, which is  default.

Besides that this is a know issue in bootstrap, especially if you download the customized version of bootstrap 3.

To get the correct fonts, go to the Bootstrap homepage and download the full .zip file. Extract the four font files from there to your fonts directory and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: glyphicon fonts folder]

This worked for me, I have put fonts under test folder and everything was OK

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" style="font-size: 3em;color:grey;"></span>
```

Comment: dont use " @import "